# No CSS styling after resizing browser

Tags: html, css, media

I use media queries:

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1431px) and (max-width: 1600px)" type="text/css" href="css/style1600.css" />

</head>
```

It works on full window browser, but when I resize browser all CSS styling just goes away.

Comment: Do you really understand what does `(min-width: 1431px) and (max-width: 1600px)` means? Your styles are applied when your resolution is between those values.

Comment: Okay. So how should I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using media queries so that the styles defined in your stylesheet will only get applied when the browser width is between **1431px** and **1600px**.  So if you resize your browser window to **800px** these styles will no longer apply.

If you want the styles to apply to the whole document you should remove the media query so it looks like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/style1600.css" />
```

Or you could use two stylesheets

```
<!-- These styles apply to the who document -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/style1600.css" />
<!-- These only apply when the browser width is between 1431px and 1600px -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1431px) and (max-width: 1600px)" type="text/css" href="css/style1600.css" />
```

If you don't know much about media queries at the moment [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) is a guide article to get you started